# OpenAL/OpenAL Soft

Tags: c, openal

OpenAL.org && creative dev website is down. I choose alternative version [OpenAL Soft](http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal.html). I'm worried because in binary installation of OpenAL Soft I can't find the `alut.h` header. What is the purpose of the `alut.h` header? What change this header make if I had one?

Oh and one more thing. I take a simple code from this (ZIP in description)[tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V83Ja4FmrqE) and translate in C language. I actually get a sound but it's deformed. I wonder what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <OPENAL/al.h>
#include <OPENAL/alc.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp=fopen("WAVE/Sound.wav","rb");

char type[4];
DWORD size,chunkSize;
short formatType,channels;
DWORD sampleRate,avgBytesPerSec;
short bytesPerSample,bitsPerSample;
DWORD dataSize;

fread(type,sizeof(char),4,fp);
fread(&size, sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);
fread(type, sizeof(char),4,fp);
fread(type,sizeof(char),4,fp);
fread(&chunkSize,sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);
fread(&formatType,sizeof(short),1,fp);
fread(&channels,sizeof(short),1,fp);
fread(&sampleRate,sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);
fread(&avgBytesPerSec,sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);
fread(&bytesPerSample,sizeof(short),1,fp);
fread(&bitsPerSample,sizeof(short),1,fp);
fread(type,sizeof(char),4,fp);
fread(&dataSize,sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);

ALCdevice *device;
ALCcontext *context;
device = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
context = alcCreateContext(device, NULL);
alcMakeContextCurrent(context);

ALuint source;
ALuint buffer;
ALuint frequency=sampleRate;
ALenum format=0;

alGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
alGenSources(1, &source);

if(bitsPerSample == 8)
{
    if(channels == 1)
        format = AL_FORMAT_MONO8;
    else if(channels == 2)
        format = AL_FORMAT_STEREO8;
}
else if(bitsPerSample == 16)
{
    if(channels == 1)
        format = AL_FORMAT_MONO16;
    else if(channels == 2)
        format = AL_FORMAT_STEREO16;
}

alBufferData(buffer, format, "24641", dataSize, frequency);

//Sound setting variables
ALfloat SourcePos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };                                    //Position of the source sound
ALfloat SourceVel[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };                                    //Velocity of the source sound
ALfloat ListenerPos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };                                  //Position of the listener
ALfloat ListenerVel[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };                                  //Velocity of the listener
ALfloat ListenerOri[] = { 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };                 //Orientation of the listener

alListenerfv(AL_POSITION,    ListenerPos);                                  //Set position of the listener
alListenerfv(AL_VELOCITY,    ListenerVel);                                  //Set velocity of the listener
alListenerfv(AL_ORIENTATION, ListenerOri);                                  //Set orientation of the listener

alSourcei (source, AL_BUFFER,   buffer);                                    //Link the buffer to the source
alSourcef (source, AL_PITCH,    1.0f     );                                 //Set the pitch of the source
alSourcef (source, AL_GAIN,     1.0f     );                                 //Set the gain of the source
alSourcefv(source, AL_POSITION, SourcePos);                                 //Set the position of the source
alSourcefv(source, AL_VELOCITY, SourceVel);                                 //Set the velocity of the source
alSourcei (source, AL_LOOPING,  AL_FALSE );                                 //Set if source is looping sound

//PLAY 
alSourcePlay(source);                                                       //Play the sound buffer linked to the source
system("PAUSE");                                                            //Pause to let the sound play

//Clean-up
fclose(fp);                                                           //Delete the sound data buffer
alDeleteSources(1, &source);                                                //Delete the OpenAL Source
alDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer);                                                 //Delete the OpenAL Buffer
alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);                                                //Make no context current
alcDestroyContext(context);                                                 //Destroy the OpenAL Context
alcCloseDevice(device);                                                     //Close the OpenAL Device

return EXIT_SUCCESS;                                                        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alBufferData(buffer, format, "24641", dataSize, frequency);
```

You passing "24641" byte array as sound. Aside from it is very very quick sound - dataSize is sure to be much larger, so you actually reading much more. And playing this garbage.

I don't know WAV format well, as i see - you don't reading actual waveforms data from file, only it's header. Check WAV doc. Guessing just after header you need to allocate dataSize bytes array and read it from rest of the file, then pass it to alBufferData.

And no, your code doesn't use alut, so you don't need it. It's small utility library that handles context creating - you doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Ha I find it!    ---> [FreeAlut](https://github.com/vancegroup/freealut)
And this should work:

```
alutLoadWAVFile("XXX.wav", &format, &data, &size, &freq, &loop);
```